# Compare two excel tables based on unique key using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables with same column names in excel which are getting data from two different sources based on certain calculations. We need to compare data between those two tables based on ID column value which will be provided by user in A2. I have attached snapshot of sample tables. I did try using sumproduct (as you can see in K2, but it doesn't work if any of the cell values has #NA as it's value. Please keep in mind that calculations update data for only a particular id  (one row only for each table). in this example, values for only the rows with ID 200 will be updated for these two tables.

If I change value from #NA to an integer, formula (in K2) would work. Now I was even thinking about using if(And(logic1,logic2...)) to compare cell to cell values,but I don't kow how would I use it when the placement of ID's in columns C and G can vary and won't necessarly be in the same row.

Formula used:

`=IF(G2:G5=A2,IF(SUMPRODUCT((G2:G5=A2)*(H2:I5))-SUMPRODUCT((C2:C5=A2)*(D2:E5))=0,"Match","No Match"),"")`

[image]

Comment: My bad @BigBen, formula added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help get you started.

```
=IF(AND(IF($A$2=G3,VLOOKUP(G3,C3:E6,2,0),"")=H3,IF($A$2=G3,VLOOKUP(G3,C3:E6,3,0),"")=I3),"Match","No Match")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, this does work. only downside is that it's going to become such a long formula if number of columns to compare are like 7 or more. I wish there was a  something compact. I am accepting your answer @jsteurer as it does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I don't think it's still handling #NA any good. Please change value for A2 to 3000 and see if you get no match or #NA as output

Comment: Wrap it with an iferror like=IFERROR(IF(AND(IF($A$2=G2,VLOOKUP(G2,$C$2:$E$5,2,0),"")=H2,IF($A$2=G2,VLOOKUP(G2,$C$2:$E$5,3,0),"")=I2),"Match","No Match"),"No Match")

Answer (score 0):

Try following array formula:

```
=INDEX({"No Match","Match"},1,IFERROR(--(MATCH(COLUMNS($C$2:$E$2),MMULT(--(INDEX($C$2:$E$5,MATCH($A$2,$C$2:$C$5,0),0)=$G$2:$I$5),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($C$2:$E$2)^0)),0)>0)+1,0))
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]